# Format HTML output of a Pandas dataframe based on row and column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code which outputs an HTML table:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Color': ['Red', 'Red', 'Yellow', 'Yellow'],
    'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Strawberry', 'Banana', 'Peach'],
    'Weight': [5, 3, 8, 6]
})

df = pd.pivot(df, index='Color', columns='Fruit', values='Weight')

print(df.to_html())
```

I would like the output of each cell to reference its row (index) and column value. For example, I'd like a format function that looks like this:

```py
def format_value(val, row, col):
    return f"<a href=/{row}/{col}>{val}</a>"
```

However, I cannot figure out how to do this. This is what I've tried:

### df.applymap()

```py
df = df.applymap(lambda x: format_value(x, row=x.index, col=x.name))
```

This returns an error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'index'
```

### to_html(formatter=...)

```
def format_cell(val, col, row):

    def f(val):
      return f"/{row}/{col}"
            
    return f

format_map = {}
for col in df.columns:
    format_map[col] = format_cell(col, df.index)

print(df.to_html(formatter=format_map))
```

However, `df.index` returns all of the indexes, so there is no way to know which row specifically the formatter is referring to.

### Create a new dataframe

I was able to make this work in a cumbersome way, by creating a new dataframe and using `iterrows()`:

```py
df_formatted = df.copy()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for c in df.columns:
        df_formatted[c][index] = f"<a href=/{index}/{c}>{df[c][index]}</a>"
```

How can I create an HTML formatter which is aware of both the index and column for each value?

Comment: You were _extremely_ close with `applymap()`, it should work with `apply()`.

Comment: Would you be willing to elucidate a bit? `apply()` passes a Series as input. I am not able to run `applymap()` against the series.

I could say `for i in val.index: val[i].???` but I'm not sure how to format `val[i]` which is a scalar value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest thing I can come up with:

```
def format_value(val, row, col):
    return f"<a href=/{row}/{col}>{val}</a>"


def format_row(row):
    for col in row.index:
        row[col] = format_value(row[col], row.name, col)
    return row


df_copy = df.copy()
print(df_copy.apply(format_row, axis=1).to_html(escape=False))
```

Essentially, it uses apply() to loop over each row. That function is passed a Series, which you can get the index of using `.name`. It also turns off escaping so that the links render properly.